# SQL Server 2005 I/O Restrictions

Tags: sql-server-2005, electrical-power, central-processing-unit

We have a few databases on the server.  One database is tied to an application that likes to spike the I/O and processor to high levels.  Is there a way to limit one of the databases to less processing power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to limit one of the
>   databases to less processing power?

No.

2008 - yes (Resource Governor). Sadly that is a new feature in 2008. I suggest an update to 2008 R2.

> One database is tied to an application
>   that likes to spike the I/O and
>   processor to high levels

Most apps should do that - not necessarily OFTEN, but SQL Server likes to use up all CPU it can to finish a complex query ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

If the database is thrashing the CPU and disks you my have a bad query which needs tuning.